# celery how to implement single queue with multiple workers executing in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

I am currently running celery 4.0.2 with a single worker like this:

celery.py:

```
app = Celery('project',
         broker='amqp://jimmy:jimmy123@localhost/jimmy_vhost',
         backend='rpc://',
         include=['project.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
    app.name
```

tasks.py:

```
from .celery import app
from celery.schedules import schedule
from time import sleep, strftime

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'planner_1': {
        'task': 'project.tasks.call_orders',
        'schedule': 1800,
    },
    'planner_2': {
        'task': 'project.tasks.call_inventory',
        'schedule': 900,
    },
}
```

I used the following command to run with beat:

```
 celery -A project worker -l info --concurrency=3 --beat -E
```

Right now it is only a single queue with only one worker running.

> My question is how to run celery with multiple workers and single queue so that tasks are executed in parallel using multiprocessing without duplication?

I looked up on the internet, how to run celery with multiprocessing. According to [this](https://www.quora.com/Celery-distributed-task-queue/Celery-distributed-task-queue-What-is-the-difference-between-workers-and-processes) article:

> `celery worker -l info -P processes -c 16`
>   will result in a single message consumer delegating work to
>   16 OS-level pool processes.  Each OS-level process can be assigned to different CPU in a multicore environment, and as such it will process tasks
>   in parallel, but it will not consume messages in parallel.

can using the `-p processes` argument solve my problem? Also but what is meant by, "it will process tasks in parallel, but it will not consume messages in parallel"?